# There is a fatality about all physical and intellectual distinction

Tags: meaning, literary-techniques, paraphrasing

I am reading *The Picture of Dorian Gray* by Oscar Wilde, and I came across this paragraph

> There is a fatality about all physical and intellectual distinction, the sort of fatality that seems to dog through history the faltering steps of kings. It is better not to be different from one's fellows. The ugly and the stupid have the best of it in this world. They can sit at their ease and gape at the play. If they know nothing of victory, they are at least spared the knowledge of defeat. They live as we all should live, undisturbed, indifferent, and without disquiet.

I could not comprehend the meaning of this paragraph, I know that the gist of it  is something related to "ignorance is bliss" but the beginning of this paragraph is perplexing me.

Can somebody help me understand with an example, *“the fatality of physical and intellectual distinction”* and how it is related to *“the faltering steps of kings.”* 
Oxford Dictionaries tells me that the noun [**fatality**](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/us/fatality) has two separate meanings

> 1. An occurrence of death by accident, in war, or from disease.

and

> 2. Helplessness in the face of fate.

- What did the author mean by “fatality of physical and intellectual distinction”? Was Wilde referring specifically to death or to destiny?

Comment: I believe I left this comment on the earlier question you asked and deleted, but this kind of question is off-topic here (from the [help/on-topic]: no ***[criticism, discussion, [or] analysis of English literature***). You can ask it on [Literature.se] (or wait for a moderator here to migrate it there, though that might take a long time if it happens at all), but you'll probably get a warmer welcome there if you indicate what your own googling and other research has turned up on the passage.

Comment: what is wrong with this question Dan ?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is a request for literary analysis, which is off-topic according to our help center.

Comment: @DayanandChaudhary What I told you in my first comment, the bolded part, and also the same thing I told you the first time around before you deleted your question, and also what tchrist (a mod) just told you. This site is for analyzing the *mechanics* of English: morphology, syntax, etymology, orthography, etc. interpretation is off-topic. Literature.se might take it if you add more details around what your own research has turned up to date.

Comment: This question would be on-topic in [Literature.SE].

Comment: @Mick So I told OP in my two comments (and in the comment on his earlier identical question which he deleted).

Comment: If you could be more specific and say what expression, or line you do not understand that would already be a great help. For instance, let's say you didn't know that *dog* could also be used as a verb, and despite looking up its meaning, you still fail to grasp the meaning of the sentence where it is employed. You'd post a link to the dictionary which would clearly show that its definition does not seem to fit. For instance..., obviously if the definition fits there's no question.

Comment: You mentioned having trouble with the initial part, which I suppose is "There is a fatality about all physical and intellectual distinction, the sort of fatality that seems to dog through history the faltering steps of kings."  Look up *fatality* and make sure you've got that word.  "Dog" might be a little hard to find -- as a verb, if my three-year-old *dogs my steps*, that means he follows me around like my shadow. // Please edit your question as suggested by @Mari-LouA.

Comment: @aparente001 I made the required edits as suggested by you.

Comment: *Distinction* = *being different* in that quote. The force of the opening remark there is similar to '[tall poppy syndrome](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tall_poppy_syndrome)'.

Comment: Hello Dayanand Chaudhary, I've shifted the focus of your question towards the ambiguity of *fatality*, and showed some research by citing a resource. If you dislike, or disapprove of the edit, please rollback to the version you prefer. You can visit the [edit history](http://english.stackexchange.com/posts/380123/revisions) and click where it says `rollback`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to the [Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Picture_of_Dorian_Gray) on this topic, *The Picture of Dorian Gray* was "first published complete in the July 1890 issue *Lippincott's Monthly Magazine*." That same year, Merriam-Webster published its massive *Webster's International Dictionary*—a volume that lists three definitions in its entry for *fatality*:

> **Fatality** *n.* ... **1.** The state of being fatal, or proceeding from destiny ; invincible necessity, superior to, and independent of, free and rational control. [Example:] The Stoics held a *fatality*, and a fixed, unalterable course of events. *South[ey]*. **2.** The state of being fatal ; tendency to destruction or danger, as if by decree of fate ; mortality [Examples:] The year sixty-three is conceived to carry with it the most considerable *fatality*. *Sir T[homas] Browne*. *By a strange *fatality* men suffer their dissenting. *Eikon Basilike*. 3. That which is decreed by fate or which is fatal : a fatal event. *Dryden.*

Of these three definitions, the one closest to what Wilde seems to have had in mind in his sentence "There is a fatality about all physical and intellectual distinction, the sort of fatality that seems to dog through history the faltering steps of kings" is the second one—a "tendency to destruction or danger." If so, Wilde may be asserting that a connection exists between being exceptional in physical or mental abilities and being in greater danger of destruction, as if at the hands of jealous Fates. Wilde seems to suggest that, by standing out from the safety and anonymity of the crowd (or the average), one exposes oneself to a heightened risk of being singled out for ruin.

Neither of the online Oxford Dictionaries definitions that you cite covers this sense of *fatality* at all well, and I don't think it is accurate to describe the "state of being fatal ; tendency to destruction or danger, as if by decree or fate ; mortality" meaning as obsolete or archaic. It seems to me that I encounter *fatality* used in this sense too often to consider it rare—but I do read a lot of old books.

*Merriam-Webster's Collegiate Dictionary*, eleventh edition (2003) also yields more definitions of *fatality* than you might expect from the online Oxford Dictionaries' treatment of the word:

> **fatality** *n* ... (15c) **1 a :** the quality or state of causing death or destruction **b :** the quality or condition of being being destined for disaster **2 :** something established by fate **3 a :** FATE [in the sense of 'destiny"] **b :** FATALISM [in the sense of "the doctrine that events are fixed in advance" of their happening] **4 :** the agent or agency of fate **5 a :** death resulting from a disaster **b :** on that experiences a fatal outcome

Of these definitions of *fatality*, 1(a) seems the closest to the sense that Wilde had in mind in his sentence.